# Tool or addon for showing textures on PC

Tags: materials, add-on

I'm fairly new to Blender, but have done some small things and a lot of tutorials in Blender.

Due to this I now have a lot of different textures on my pc, but am lacking the tool or addon for Blender that can easily show what I already have.

I can of course just use the explorer and do searches, but is there or are there tools, that can show me my textures, like the preview under texture?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you tried IrfanView or some other Image-Database Tool - organizing your stuff is highly recommend !

Comment: I have organized by stuff :-) but are needing the tool in Blender that presents the texture (including bump, displacement, color...) in a preview form (like you can do on the texture tab. This an help me when I have 10 different wood floors for a plane and need to find the one that "looks the best". 

with a "simple" image tool, I just get the different images one by one

it might not exist, but a kind of texture assets addon

Comment: Unfortunately Blender doesn't have an automatic material preview functionality. As of yet, there are only add-ons (also paid ones) who deal with asset- and material management.

Comment: Metaphor - Which add-ons exist for this - have tried to look, but can not find some that matches my requerments.
(I will also of course pay for others work if they are worth it)